# Correct way to define all in robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

Is the correct way of defining allow all or disallow all in robots to use `Allow: /`?

I've seen a variation on this using a `*` rather than a `/`.
`Allow: *`

Is the `*` method valid?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to allow everything is to disallow nothing:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

See "To allow all robots complete access" on the [official robots.txt website](https://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html).

The `Allow` directive was introduced by Google. It is meant to be an exception to a `Disallow`.  For example to disallow all crawling except for a single directory:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
Allow: /public/
```

The major search engines know how to process `Allow` directives, but most robots do not.

That being said, both of the following will **probably** allow all crawling for the vast majority of bot user agents:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

```
User-agent: *
Allow: *
```

Bots that don't understand `Allow` will ignore that line and see no rules at all.  When there are no rules, most bots assume they are allowed to crawl.

Bots that understand `Allow` typically also understand wildcards. For them the two rules should be synonymous.  All URLs paths start with a slash, and all URL paths also match the wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you mah have seen is * in front of user-agent part of robots.txt file.

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

That * means all (in this case all user-agents)
and that / means all URLs.

```
Allow: /blog
```

The above code just allows URL that contain /blog.

For more information here is google's document:
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/robots/create-robots-txt